# Office 365 sharepoint online main search to automatically default to current context (especially if used from library or list)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-results, result-source

there is a setting in Sharepoint 2010 under search settings you can set the search to default contextual scope.  This setting automatically defaults search to the current contextual scope and only shows search results from that context. If searched from the current site it shows content from the current site, if searched from the current library it shows content from the current library only. See below
Image

[image: Above image shows how you can accomplish that in SharePoint 2010]

I am trying to configure office 365 SharePoint online search to automatically default to current contextual scope means it only shows search results from current context (this includes list level context too).

If the main search is used from the current site it would show content from the current site, if the main search used from the current library it should show content from that library only. However, I do not see an option to configure office 365 search as above which would default to contextual scope (to list/library level) similar to Sharepoint 2010.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Is there a way I can automatically set u parameter to have current site/current library context in it ? `{ContextUrl}` only resolves to the current site.

Using search box provided within list/library in office 365 returns results but they are sorted based on title/name not based on search relevance which is confusing because you search for a document and it appears at the bottom because its name starts with z, so this search is confusing and not that appealing as compared to main SharePoint search.

Please let me know if there is a way to automatically achieve current contextual scope (current library/list) in office 365 SharePoint online. I know you can manually create scopes for libraries but this is not what I want.